# Rotate View and update its content while rotating

Tags: android, animation

I want to rotate a `View` to 90 degree and update its content and again rotate it to 90 degree, and so far I tried below code.

```
ObjectAnimator anim1 = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.animator.flip_animator);

                    anim1.setTarget(v);
                    anim1.setDuration(1000);
                    anim1.start();


ImageView box = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.box);
        Bitmap bg = BoxUtils.getBoxBg(boxSize, boxMargin, Color.RED);
        box.setImageBitmap(bg);


                anim1.setTarget(v);
                anim1.setDuration(1000);
                anim1.start();
```

xml:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:valueFrom="0" android:valueTo="90" android:propertyName="rotationY" >
</objectAnimator>
```

However its working but its changing its color before it rotates next 90 degree, even i had written updation code before than next rotation code.
Any help ?

Comment: So what your saying is rotate 90 degrees, change color, then rotate again?

Comment: yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your object rotates asynchronously from your code. You have designed it so that the code sits there while the cube does the first rotation, then changes the color. What happens is that the code starts the animation, then keeps running as the cube rotates, which is why it changes color early.

The following method of animating your view will add an end action, which will be changing color then rotating the last 90:

```
View v;
v.animate()
.rotationY(90)
.setDuration(1000)
.withEndAction(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    ImageView box = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.box);
    Bitmap bg = BoxUtils.getBoxBg(boxSize, boxMargin, Color.RED);
    box.setImageBitmap(bg);

    v.animate().rotationY(90).setDuration(1000).start();
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: I cant access `v` inside `run()` method of `Runnable()` !

Comment: v is meant to refer to the view you are trying to animate. the one I use is an example, you will want to declare your own via `findViewById(R.id.your-object)`